# Displaying feature name using Openlayers and GEOServer

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to display feature name in the map while loading (ex: name of the building).

How we can display this in **OpenLayers** by using **GeoServer**.

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

You need to define TextSymbolizer for the feature using styles in geoserver. Go to geoserver admin --> Styles --> Add a new style.

Add a TextSymblolizer as follows

```
<sld:NamedLayer xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <sld:UserStyle>
        <sld:Name>layer_name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Title>layer_title</sld:Title>
        <sld:Abstract/>
        <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
            <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>

            <sld:Rule>
                <sld:Name>rule01</sld:Name>                             
                <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                    <sld:Label>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>feature_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </sld:Label>
                    <sld:Font>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</sld:CssParameter>
                      <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12</sld:CssParameter>
                    </sld:Font>


                    <sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:PointPlacement>
                        <sld:AnchorPoint>
                            <sld:AnchorPointX>
                                0.5
                            </sld:AnchorPointX>
                            <sld:AnchorPointY>
                                0.5
                            </sld:AnchorPointY>
                        </sld:AnchorPoint>
                        </sld:PointPlacement>
                    </sld:LabelPlacement>            
                </sld:TextSymbolizer>
            </sld:Rule>
        </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
</sld:NamedLayer>
```

Within the  tag define the feature whose value needs to be displayed. 
Next associate the given layer with this style, update and reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WMS layers, try with [SLD styles](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html). But,if you are using vector layers, you must to use OpenLayers StyleMap [to label your features](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/vector-features-with-text.html), try this

```
var style = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    default :new OpenLayers.Style({
          'label': '${feature_attr}'
    })
})
```